# Excel: I want to sort a column based on modifier list of words

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula, tablesorter

I have a single column in an excel with 275 (cells) sentences. Now I've to sort the column

Condition: I want to sort the column based on a modifier list.
Modifier List: This list contains keywords (1 keyword in each cell) that may exist in the beginning, end or in the middle of the sentence in the column mentioned above.

For example

**Parent Column**

- **Jack** lives in the village
- As mentioned by **jack**
- Rose already spoke to **jack** about last night
- Rose left the village
- rose was their yesterday

  **Modifier (Column)**
- Jack
- Rose
- Village

Comment: Is VBA allowed?

Comment: yes, I can use that If tell me the instructions

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way but it may help:

[image]

First of all, you need a helper column on your modifier list. You need to specify an **unique** numeric value to each of your modifiers, being the first criteria the **highest** value and the last criteria the **lowest**.

As example, I did `Jack` was the most important, `Rose` second one and finally `Village`.

My formula will check if the phrase containg any of the modifier words, and will choose the highest value if there is any match, returning 0 if there is no matches.

My formula in B2 is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COUNTIF(A2;"*"&$A$13:$A$15&"*")*$B$13:$B$15))
```

This is how it works:

1. `COUNTIF(A2;"*"&$A$13:$A$15&"*")` will return an array of 1 and o if the phrase contain the modifier word or not. As example, phrase `Jack lives in the village` will return `{1;0;1}` (`Rose` modifier is not there)
2. We multiply the array from previous step by their modifier value so we added `*$B$13:$B$15`. So we do `{1;0;1} * {3;2;1}= {3;0;1}`
3. With `MAX` we get the highest value from previous step (we get `3`) and that's how important is that phrase.
4. `SUMPRODUCT` is just added so we can work as array formula and sum up the max value.

Once obtained, sort your phrases using that column, from highest to lowest.

If you change the values from modifier list, sort again from highest to lowest:

[image]

Note now I'm giving more value to phrases containing `Rose` so they get sorted first.

Comment: @P082 Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

### Sort By Contained Values

- Sorts a `Parent` list using a `Modifier` list.
- The code emulates something like this: takes the first value of `Modifier` and checks if it is contained in any item of `Parent`. If it is, writes the current `Parent` value to a `Result` list. Then it takes the second value of `Modifier` and does the same ... Finally it writes the remainder (the items that had no match) to `Result` and replaces `Parent` with `Result`.

**Instructions**

- Save your file as a **macro-enabled workbook** (`.xlsm`).
- Open the **Visual Basic Editor (VBE)** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>).
- In the **Project Explorer** locate your file. Right-click anywhere in it and select `Insert Module`.
- Copy the following code into the window that opens (usually `Module1`).
- Adjust the values in the constants section of the code to fit your needs i.e. adjust the first 3 value pairs. In each pair, the first value refers to the location of the `Parent` column, while the second value refers to the location of the `Modifier` column.
- Save the file: either in **VBE** or in **Excel**.
- To run the code from **VBE** you can use either `Run>Run Sub` or press the 'play' button or use <kbd>F5</kbd> .
- To run the code from **Excel**, use `Developer>Macro` and locate `sortByCriteria`. Either double-click it or select it and click Run.
- Additionally you could create a button to run the code.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortByCriteria()
    ' Constants
    Dim SheetNames As Variant: SheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet1")
    Dim FirstRows As Variant: FirstRows = Array(2, 2)
    Dim Cols As Variant: Cols = Array("A", "B")
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook with this code.

    ' Write Modifier and Parent ranges to Modifier (Data(1)) and Parent
    ' (Data(0)) Arrays.
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, j As Long
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1)
    For j = 1 To 0 Step -1
        ' Define current Column Range.
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SheetNames(j))
        Set rng = ws.Columns(Cols(j)).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If rng.Row < FirstRows(j) Then Exit Sub
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRows(j), Cols(j)), rng)
        ' Write current Column Range to current Column Array.
        Dim OneCell As Variant: ReDim OneCell(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            Data(j) = rng.Value
        Else
            Data(j) = OneCell: Data(j) = rng.Value
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Write values from Data Array (Data(0)) to Result Array (Result).
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To UBound(Data(0)), 1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, m As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data(1))
        For k = 1 To UBound(Data(0))
            If Not IsEmpty(Data(0)(k, 1)) Then
                If InStr(1, Data(0)(k, 1), Data(1)(i, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 _
                        Then
                    m = m + 1
                    Result(m, 1) = Data(0)(k, 1)
                    Data(0)(k, 1) = Empty ' Already checked and written.
                End If
            End If
            
        Next k
    Next i
    For k = 1 To UBound(Data(0))
        If Not IsEmpty(Data(0)(k, 1)) Then
            m = m + 1
            Result(m, 1) = Data(0)(k, 1)
            Data(0)(k, 1) = Empty ' Already checked and written.
        End If
    Next k
    If m = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write values from Result Array (Result) to Data Range (rng).
    rng.Resize(m).Value = Result
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```